# Rise error when try to delete protected foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django

I want the user  to see an error message when he tries to delete a value that is being used as PROTECTED Foreign key for another table, and the table is not empty which means there are values under this Foreign key.. it returns back an error for me in debug mode but I want an error message for end user ...

**view.py**

```
def cat_delete(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Categories, pk=pk)
    instance.delete()
    return redirect('/')
```

**urls.py**

```
path('category/<int:pk>/delete/', views.cat_delete, name="cat_delete"),
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="{%url 'cat_delete' cat.pk%}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" >تأكيد المسح</button></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Django Messages Framwork](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/)

Your `cat_delete` view:

```
from django.contrib import messages
...

def cat_delete(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Categories, pk=pk)
    try:
        instance.delete()
    except Exception as e:
        messages.error(request, "Your error message")
    return redirect('/')
```

In your html template, error message will be visible under `messages` variable. You can use the following snippet to display it:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```